# Calling `ksh` from `ksh` script stops execution

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I am executing a `ksh` script from another `ksh` script. The called script ends by executing `ksh` which simply stops the caller script from continuing.

MRE

```
#!/bin/ksh
# Caller Script

. ~/called
# Does not continue to next echo.
echo "DONE!"
```

```
#!/bin/ksh
#Called script

# Some exports..

ENV=calledcalled ksh
```

Output with `set -x`

```
++ ksh
++ ENV=calledcalled
.kshrc executed
```

If I run `calledcalled` directly in my caller it works fine (i.e. continues with next commands. Why does this happen? I checked `$?` and it is `0`. I tried `./called || true`. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Note: Called script is outside my control.

Comment: Why would you expect it _not_ to happen? When you run a command in the foreground within a script, execution of the script doesn't continue until that command exits. If the new copy of ksh doesn't exit, the parent process never continues.

Comment: What are you expecting the `ksh` command to do?

Comment: Another thing you could do, btw, is run `. ~/called </dev/null`; if the copy of ksh can't find any code to run on stdin it should exit.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The MRE was not sufficient. `ENV` was being set along with the call to `ksh`. Updated the question details (code and last paragraph) @GordonDavisson

Comment: Please label your 2 scripts with their names. If I read you correctly, do you have a script named `calledcalled`? I'm not sure about sourcing `. ~/called`. Try just plain `~/called`. Also, so the last thing that happens is you calling a new `ksh` (at the bottom of your 2n included script)? I would think that would launch a shell that is waiting to read input. Try typing "echo hello world" and pressing the enter key. Do you get any output? And finally, in some environments `ENV` var has a special meaning. I don't think you want to use that here. maybe `myENV`  or similar. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks for the response! I naively thought "end of script == end of child shell". The prompt returned was to the child shell which I misinterpreted as the parent's thus thinking the script did finish.

Comment: I've come late to the party. You have some good explanations below (somehow my browser didn't display them until after I had finished typing that up). Glad you've solved your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely normal and expected. Remember, when you run `cmd1; cmd2`, `cmd2` doesn't run *until `cmd1` exits*.

When your script runs `ksh` (and is invoked from a terminal or other context where reading from stdin doesn't cause an immediate EOF), nothing is making that new copy of ksh exit -- it waits for code to run to be given to it on stdin as normal -- so that script is just sitting around waiting for the copy of `ksh` to exit before it does anything else.

There are plenty of ways you can work around this. A few easy ones:

- Ensure that stdin is empty so the child interpreter can't wait for input

  ```
  . ~/called </dev/null
  ```
- Define a *function* named ksh that doesn't do anything at all.

  ```
  ksh() { echo "Not actually running ksh" >&2; }
  . ~/called
  ```
- Set `ENV` (a variable which, when defined, tells any shell to run the code in that file before doing anything else) to the filename of a script that, when run, causes any interactive shell to exit immediately.

  ```
  exit_script=$(mktemp -t exit_script.XXXXXX)
  printf '%s\n' 'case $- in *i*) exit 0;; esac' >"$exit_script"
  ENV=$exit_script . ~/called
  rm -f -- "$exit_script"
  ```

The above are just a few approaches; you can surely imagine many more with just a little thought and experimentation.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The script does set `ENV` along with the call to `ksh`. I missed it's purpose. It went to another script but still doesn't explain why it just stops. If I run the commands in the `ENV` script myself it prints ton of stuff and continues just fine.

Comment: It doesn't "just stop". You aren't returning to your old shell, you're getting plunked into a *new* shell, and the program is waiting for that new shell to exit. Unless the ENV script is doing something that hangs, but obviously we can't tell that from there when you haven't included it in evidence.

Comment: I get `.kshrc executed` as the output and the terminal prompt. Are you saying it continues running in the background never finishes the `echo` after it?

Comment: I'm saying it's calling `waitpid()` as the third leg of the `fork()`/`execve()`/`wait()` triad of launching a new program and pausing until it's finished, thus hanging until the new copy of ksh it started exits. If you're typing commands into that new copy of ksh thinking it was your original shell, that new shell's not exiting, so the script keeps being stuck waiting.

Comment: If the above is in fact what's happening, btw, you'll see it in `pstree` -- every time you run the script the tree will get deeper with a new copy of ksh under the previous one.

Comment: Should that not be it, btw, a useful thing to do would be to add the command `set -x` both to your immediate script, and to your `.kshrc`; that way you'll get trace logs of what the shell is actually up to. This answer is the most plausible theory given the question as-asked, but if there are other things going on that we haven't been given evidence for yet... well, some evidence is called for in order to run the other possibilities down.

Comment: "If you're typing commands into that new copy of ksh thinking it was your original shell, that new shell's not exiting" that explains it!! Also `< /dev/null` did the trick non-intrusively! Thank you very much.

Comment: On the same note, what would be appropriate an way to end the child shell? call to `exit` at end of the "called" script? @CharlesDuffy

Comment: I consider the `</dev/null` a very appropriate way to do that :) -- it sees end-of-input so it exits, and there you are.